# NVIDIA_SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hp, gpu

We have bought the HP z4 g4 workstation with windows and I have uninstalled windows and installed ubuntu 18.04. While installing, I have got so many errors and I have corrected using online sources. But now, I am trying to install the nvidia-driver and installed the latest nvidia-driver (430) but when I check it with nvidia-smi, I am getting the following error.

I have installed nvidia-driver using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-430
```

NVIDIA_SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest sriver is installed and running

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
```

The above command produces the following output

```
00:1f.5 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset F                                                                                        amily SPI Controller
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
21:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e30 (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 129e
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
21:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f7 (rev a1)
```

I have tried many possibilities but I couldn't correct and your help towards this is highly appreciated.

I have the following properites in secure boot[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QnTDLKnjPVWnKzyOIF2hgafmvPkgoCKV/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: How did you install the driver? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Please EDIT YOUR QUESTION and add output there. It is unreadable in comments.

Comment: I have updated the comment. please check it.

Comment: There is no `nvidia-430` package for ubuntu 18.04. Did your install command install anything? Also check if Secure Boot is disabled in BIOS.

Comment: Yes, it installed some libraries. Even I have tried with .run package. This also didn't work. I have uninsalled all the nvidia drivers. Now nvidia-smi prodduces the following output:  Command 'nvidia-smi' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nvidia-340
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-390

Comment: Please add all additional info TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Ubuntu 18.04? Please add output of `cat /etc/lsb-release`

Comment: DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"

Comment: Can you read? Edit your question for additional info. Don't post it to comments. And I gave a solution on how to install the driver properly below.

Comment: Choose `Legacy support disable and secure boot disable`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99918/discussion-between-vinayakumar-r-and-pilot6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install the driver properly disable Secure Boot in BIOS if you are using UEFI and install by

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430
```

In your case the correct BIOS option is

```
Legacy Support Disable and Secure Boot Disable
```

Comment: I have installed using the same command and the secure boot option which I have is given in the attached image (in the above question)