# Ubuntu 20.04 compatibility with nvidia-driver-390

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

The graphics card used to work before doing my last update. Now even if it is installed it doesn't work. So I think the problem is that this driver isn't supported by the kernel anymore. But I can't install newer drivers because my card is not supported by them.

If I run:

`nvidia-settings`

I get this error:

`ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded`

If I run:

`nvidia-smi`

I get this error:

`NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.`

The only thing I think is a sure solution is downgrading my kernel. However i don't want to do that, is there another viable solution for this problem?

The model of my card is: Geforce GT 635M

Comment: Have You disabled "secure bios" like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181110/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver?rq=1)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mainline` package to install kernel 5.11.0 and `460.56` nvidia driver. This combination works. Just confirmed here, although I see more recent kernel versions available, can check later if needed.

Comment: My card is only supported by the 390 driver (and below). I actually tried that driver before I knew that.

Comment: sounds like pretty important thing to add to the question. Please adjust the question accordingly with the model of your card.

Comment: @jogarcia can you add the model of your card to the question?